# An oscillating skateboard

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

A half pipe of a skateboard park consists of a concrete trough with a semicircular section of radius 5m, I hold a frictionless skateboard on the side of the trough, pointing down toward the bottom and release it; how long will it take to come to back to the point of release?

Note: I am supposed to use Newton's laws and polar coordinates. The solution is already given in the book, I am just confused as to why $F_r$, the force in the radial direction, is equal to $mg\cos\theta$ minus the normal force (where $\theta$ is the angle from the origin of the half circle). Also, I am used to using the vector form of Newton's laws in polar coordinates and not using conservation of energy or free fall or anything else.

Comment: May I suggest that you add a diagram showing the forces? Maybe that will make it clear to you.

Comment: i drew a diagram already the only part i dont get is which part of the weight contributes to the tangential component of force and which contributes to the radial component

Comment: Do you understand how a force (a vector) can be thought of as the sum of two other forces? In this case, a rectangle with one force radial, the other tangential, and the diagonal equal to the force of gravity, is what you need. Please SHOW your diagram (in the question) with these vectors in it; then we can help you further if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You really, really have to be able to draw a diagram to understand many physics problems.
Here is my interpretation of what you write above (with apologies for poor lining up of various lines due to the limitations of the drawing package I had to hand).

[image: Heaven is a half pipe]

The normal force acts at right angles to the surface and is labelled as $N$. The weight of the skateboard $mg$ acts vertically downwards. This can be resolved into two components in the radial and tangential directions - shown with red arrows and labels (they are not additional forces to $mg$).

The radial component is $mg \cos \theta$. Hence the total force in the radial direction is $F_r = mg \cos \theta - N$.